# PHP - output text one character at a time

Tags: php

Trying to create a old school terminal text effect (one character at a time with a small delay) in PHP - without javascript if possible.
All text written to the screen should go through this function.
I was thinking something like a buffer you can dynamically append text to make sure it would finish one line, before starting on the next.
Not sure how to preceed or if it's even possible without using Javascript.

Comment: If you want to do this on a HTML document, I don't think that it is possible without using javascript. However, if you run the PHP code through a terminal, you can easily delay the thread while you loop through all the characters.

Comment: PHP has output buffering, yes. There's plenty of documentation about it...did you research? You can probably do it by flushing the buffer after each character.

Comment: Yes will be through a HTML document. hmm might be an option flushing after each character and adding a sleep to the flush.

Answer (score 1):

Inefficient, but to achieve the goal you set (without javascript), you could use PHP's [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to achieve a small delay between characters output:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096); // fill the buffer
$string = 'Hello World';
$len = strlen($string);
$sleep = 0.5; // sleep half a second between output chars

for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    echo $buffer . $string[$i];
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep($sleep * 1000000);
}
```